# An array adding numbers to a specified sequence

Tags: algorithm, c, array

I have to make a program that modifies an array like this: it takes a sequence in an array and sums up a number to each element in the sequence and repeats this many times. The array's elements are `0` initially. I read the length of the array and the number of modifies I have to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    //n is the lenth of the array
    //m is the number of sets to be read
    //s and d are the edges of the sequence to be modified
    //X is the number to add to each element in the s-d interval
    //t is the array
    int n, m, s, d, X, i, j;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int t[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        t[i] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        scanf("%d %d %d", &s, &d, &X);
        for(j = s - 1; j < d; j++)
            t[j] += X;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", t[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Restrictions:

- 1 ≤ n ≤ 200.000
- 1 ≤ m ≤ 200.000
- 1 ≤ s ≤ d ≤ n
- -1000 ≤ X ≤ 1000

My code is working, but how could I make my code faster?

Input:

```
10 6
8 10 2
3 10 -3
5 9 7
5 5 5
6 7 2
1 1 -1
```

Output:

```
-1 0 -3 -3 9 6 6 6 6 -1
```

Comment: You should provide test cases.

Comment: As always, it depends. If you have a high ratio of interval size to number of intervals, or a very large *n* and only sparse data, or if you do not need every *t[i]*, it might be better to store the (interval, delta)-data, maybe even sorted. You can independently reconstruct every *t[i]* by looking just at this data array. You might even shave of some more cycles by sorting the array (so you can determine no further entry will take effect at a given *i*).

Comment: Any reason you only provide the inside of `main()` instead of the whole program?

Comment: @Deduplicator because this is the whole program. I have no other function. Shoul I include the libraries?

Comment: Sure. All-in-all, those about three extra-lines (include+method-line+closing-brace) would have made things look much better.

Comment: Is this an online [tag:programming-challenge]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a review but an extended comment.

Without giving up the solution I can only provide a (very strong) hint:

For most problems like this, the notion of the segment is a red herring. A command `s, d, X` is in fact two commands: `s, n, X` and `d+1, n, -X`. Now the algorithm should be fairly obvious. An important part is sorting the array of (split-up) commands by `s`.

Another hint is that you don't need `t`: given a sorted array of partition points you can directly print the result is a single linear scan.

Overall complexity is \$O(n + m\log{m})\$.

Comment: Okay... that was too much for me. I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't assume well-formed input

You are ignoring the return-value of `scanf`, so you have no idea whether you succeeded reading the input.
And you don't check whether the read values are sane.

### Mind your stack

`int t[n]` allocates up to 800_000 bytes on the stack (assuming `n` is really no bigger than 400_000 and `sizeof(int)` is 4).
That's easily enough to exhaust the stack, with fatal consequences, on many implementations. Consider allocating it on the heap instead.

### Restrict your variables scope.

It isn't that the compiler cannot optimize the scope of your automatic `int`-variables, but that any reader (like you) must trace them all to find their true scope and when they matter.
The fewer things you have to juggle at the same time, and the more of the are fixed, the easier things are to understand.

As a side-note, it would be better to provide a whole program for review instead of just the code inside a function.

Comment: I just forgot to say this is the whole program, but I thought it would be better not to add the `main(void)` and `return 0` to the question code.